# In JavaScript and knockout.js, why can't I return a variable? Why must I return the variable as if it's a method?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, knockout.js, return

Consider this snippet of code:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName()
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

For a while I couldn't figure out why the fullName variable wasn't working properly. But then I noticed that I need to return this.firstName() instead of return this.firstName. Why is it that way? Is it just a strange JavaScript convention or is there some reason for it? I'd like to learn more about JavaScript and Knockout for my own enjoyment which is why I'm going through Knockout's tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that way? Is it just a strange JavaScript convention or is
>   there some reason for it?

It is this way, because `this.firstName` is an observable, a function. If you want to get it's value, you should evaluate it, `this.firstName()`. Whereas, if you want to set it's value, you should pass a value in it `this.firstName("HandlerThatError")`. This is the way observables work in `knockout.js`.

Regarding the `this.fullName`, this is a computed observable. The main difference between, `this.fullName` and `this.firstName`, `this.lastName` is that the value of `this.fullName` is dependent on the values of two other observables, while the values of `this.firstName` and `this.lastName` doesn't. Hence, this is called a computed observable.

From the `knockout.js` [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> How can KO know when parts of your view model change? Answer: you need
>   to declare your model properties as observables, because these are
>   special JavaScript objects that can notify subscribers about changes,
>   and can automatically detect dependencies.

Furthermore,

> To read the observable’s current value, just call the observable with
>   no parameters.

and

> To write a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass
>   the new value as a parameter.